# How to monitor multiple macOS system usage?

Tags: macos, webserver, system-information, monitoring

For GNU/Linux systems that runs as a server, we can get a dashboard with system information like cpu, memory, network usage etc. What software is used to collect this information?
For macOS, is there any similar application where I can see all the system health of macs. I am basically looking for running a couple of macs as a server and would want to monitor the system health.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

macOS includes a graphical **Activity Monitor** application. This application provides an overview of the running processes, memory use, disk and network transfer.

## UNIX Underpinnings

macOS is a FreeBSD based operating system. So if your needs extend beyond Activity Monitor, you can use almost any popular monitoring tool you like, i.e. https://collectd.org